# How to run OpenCL + OpenGL inside a Docker container?

Tags: docker, opengl, interop, opencl, nvidia-docker

The aim is to run an OpenCL/OpenGL (interop) app inside a docker container. But I have not been successful yet.

## Intro

I have laptop with an NVidia graphics card so I thought leveraging on NVidia Dockerfiles [1,2] would be a good starting point.

The following Dockerfile:

```
# Dockerfile to run OpenGL app
FROM nvidia/opengl:1.0-glvnd-runtime-ubuntu16.04
ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES ${NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES},display
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        mesa-utils && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

works quite well, and I was able to run `glxgears`.

Running OpenCL on its own container was no big deal either:

```
# Dockerfile to run OpenCL app
FROM nvidia/opengl:1.0-glvnd-runtime-ubuntu16.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        ocl-icd-libopencl1 \
        clinfo && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN mkdir -p /etc/OpenCL/vendors && \
    echo "libnvidia-opencl.so.1" > /etc/OpenCL/vendors/nvidia.icd
ENV NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES all
ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES compute,utility
```

and `clinfo` successfully shows information about my device.

---

## Attempt

Finally here's my attempt at creating a container with both OpenGL and OpenCL drivers:

```
# Dockerfile mixing OpenGL and OpenCL
FROM nvidia/opengl:1.0-glvnd-runtime-ubuntu16.04
ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES ${NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES},display
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        mesa-utils \
        ocl-icd-libopencl1 \
        clinfo && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN mkdir -p /etc/OpenCL/vendors && \
    echo "libnvidia-opencl.so.1" > /etc/OpenCL/vendors/nvidia.icd
ENV NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES all
ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES compute,utility
```

And now, although `clinfo` still prints OpenCL device information, `glxgears` on the other hand fails with the following error:

```
Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual
```

Any idea how to make this work? Thanks in advance.

---

## References

- [1] https://gitlab.com/nvidia/opencl/blob/ubuntu16.04/devel/Dockerfile
- [2] https://gitlab.com/nvidia/opencl/blob/ubuntu16.04/runtime/Dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

```
ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES compute,utility
```

You forgot the capability `display`.

Answer (score 0):

What did work for me is the following

- STEP 1: added at the end of the Dockerfile the following two lines

  ```
    ENV NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES all
    ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES compute,utility,display
  ```
- STEP 2: to run the container

  ```
    $ sudo xhost +local:root
    $ docker run --gpus all -it --rm --name container_name \
    -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
    -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \
    -e QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 \
    --net=host \
    image_name bash
  ```