# Linking graphic card in Docker via OpenCL

Tags: docker, ubuntu, opencl

I am on Ubuntu 19.10. and would like to use OpenCL inside docker. 
Inside of the docker container I have installed opencl-headers,ocl-icd-opencl-dev and clinfo.
When I run clinfo on my machine outside of docker I have following response:

```
  Number of platforms                             1
  Platform Name                                   NVIDIA CUDA
  Platform Vendor                                 NVIDIA Corporation
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.2 CUDA 10.2.159
  ...
```

When same is run in docker:

```
Number of platforms                               0
```

I thought docker container should be able to use my graphic card, but am unsure if/how I should allow it.
Thank you for some insights

Comment: Could you try it with the official image https://hub.docker.com/r/nvidia/opencl ? Have you seen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54243119/how-to-run-opencl-opengl-inside-a-docker-container ?

Comment: Thank you for you answer. 
Yes I have seen that post. When I bluntly copy the OpenCL docker file, that is using nvidia/opencl I still get number of platforms 0. :(
What is the reason I should go with nvidia docker file? Why can't I just use simple ubuntu and install the libraries?

Answer (score 0):

You need to start docker with the `--gpus all` option, eg:

```
docker run --rm --gpus all nvidia/opencl clinfo
```

You can also expose just a specific `gpu`:

```
docker run -it --rm --gpus "device=0" ubuntu nvidia-smi
```

Read more here: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/

If you get this error:

```
$ docker run --rm --gpus all nvidia/opencl clinfo
docker: Error response from daemon: could not select device driver "" with capabilities: [[gpu]].
```

On Ubuntu, you can remedy it with:

```
$ sudo apt install -y nvidia-container-toolkit; sudo systemctl restart docker
```